# Hide "language menu" next to search bar / login menu

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

I have inherited maintanance of quite horrible looking website that is currently running version 6.x of Drupal. I am now trying to streamline / delete / disable as many unnecessary things as we can on the website.

[image]

http://sejong.ff.cuni.cz/

One of the features is a multilingual menu next to search bar / login menu. I visited the multilingual settings but I have been unable to find a way to get rid of that menu.

How can I achieve that? (I am new to Drupal so I am not sure if this is something that was custom put to the system or if it is a default Drupal feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head over to relative path `admin/build/block/list`, to bring up a list of *blocks* configured for the theme that you're using. Pretty sure you'll find a block titled something like "language switcher" (or similar to that), which is locate in your "header" region (or some other theme region). Change that to `<none>` (to not show that block in any theme region. Then check if it solved your question.

Comment: Thank you, it pointed me to the right direction (of the ideal way how it should be) but I found it hardcoded in the theme ... oh well :)